# Dialogflow simulator not responding

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am testing a simple conversation from my dialogflow simulator using a fulfillment hosted in firebase functions.

And I am receiving the fulfillment response when triggered

[image]

But my simulator is showing this. Saying no response is received.

Please help

[image]

The complete RAW fulfillment response

`{
  "responseId": "99b660de-e2ca-4d8c-ace5-ef724fe5ee72",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "male",
    "parameters": {
      "gender": "male"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "webhookPayload": {
      "google": {
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Amazing"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
      }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/assurance-purple/agent/sessions/bf891cbe-8642-eb61-ed7b-d6796adfab60/contexts/_actions_on_google",
        "lifespanCount": 99,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{}",
          "gender.original": "male",
          "gender": "male"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/assurance-purple/agent/intents/96b523a0-7a3a-4135-bdfc-d9d8ad16b661",
      "displayName": "getGender"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 45
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }
}`

My actions on google Testing debug tab

`

```
{
  "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "",
  "audioResponse": "",
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 4,
  "is3pResponse": false
}
```

`

Comment: Sorry, this action is not available for your app.
In the simulator, you are only able to invoke actions that you have added to your app. For more information on how to invoke your app, click here

Comment: The above comment is the error

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the entire response (copying and pasting it as text in your question would have been better), but it looks like you're sending a response back for an Action, but trying to test it in Dialogflow's conversation tool.

The Actions on Google response is slightly different than the response that Dialogflow expects to handle the additional features that the Assistant supports. Because of this, you need to use the Actions on Google simulator when testing your agent.

The Dialogflow test is looking for some specific fields to show the response that are not included with the actions-on-google library, and it will not show anything that is in a Google `RichResponse` object.

To summarize:

- If you are working with an Action, use the Actions on Google simulator.
- If you are working with other Dialogflow integrations, you can use the test tool on the right in Dialogflow.

**Update**

The error you're indicating from the AoG Simulator suggests that you're trying to just issue a statement in the conversation and not starting the Action, or that the Action has quit. Make sure you're talking to the action by starting it with "talk to my test app" or whatever the name of your Action is.

Comment: I did check with the Actions on google simulator. No response there either.

Comment: I gave this screenshot to show that I am receiving an response from the webhook with a reply.

Comment: I will add the raw response in a moment

Comment: If you've tested it in the AoG simulator, can you also include a cut and paste of the contents of the "request", "response", "debug" and, if available, "error" tabs? If there are logs, those might also be useful in helping you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sure, just a moment. I will add them

Comment: Updated my answer. If this doesn't seem like it addresses the issue, seeing screen shots of the AoG Simulator might help as well to see exactly what had previously happened in the conversation when you get this error.